# How to rewrite url using mod rewriter or .htaccess in wamp 2.4

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite my url from localhost/fnw/detail.php?cat=2&subcat=4&title=lol%20check%20&aid=5

to

localhost/fnw/lol%20check%20.html

I searched internet from past 3 days and i couldn't find the answer. I have enabled rewrite_mod option from wamp menu and also removed # mark from LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so in httpd.conf file. I also tried to rewrite url using mod rewrite generater tool http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ and it gave me below code to write on .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /fnw/detail.php?cat=2&subcat=4&title=$1&aid=5 [L]
```

It is not working. Can anybody help me out with this problem? Am i missing something to be changed on wamp. I am totally new on this, Looking forward for help. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Please be more specific: "It is not working." does not say much. What does that mean? Nothing happens? The wrong thing happens? An error occurs? The universe implodes?

Answer (score 0):

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE

RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$        index.php?PG=$1&NID=$2

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with WAMP. This is a problem with `mod_rewrite`.  A quick check whether it's working or not. `<IfModule>...</IfModule>` remove this.  If it returns internal server error or error code 500.  It's `mod_rewrite` ie failed to work on your WAMP. 
Than turn it ON by doing it
`Wamp -> Apache -> Apache Modules -> rewrite_module`.